# Save Form at runTime

Tags: c#, runtime, windows-forms-designer

I create a windows form at run time and I add several controls to it.

I need to save the form (run time) to disk and add it to my project (design time).

Is that possible?

Comment: You could, instead of creating the real form, just create the designer code and save that

Comment: Yes but it takes time and I search for a quick solution. The form contains more than 80 controls. Creating form, naming and arrange controls needs Time.